# Voiceover not reading nested list number

Tags: html, ios, accessibility, voiceover

How can I get voiceover on `iOS` reading the nested list number? Here is the example from `w3school`

```html
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
      <ol>
          <li>Black tea</li>
          <li>Green tea</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
1. Coffee
2. Tea
    1. Black tea
    2. Green tea
3. Milk
```

The first list, voiceover read properly ”1. Coffee” but for the second one it reads “Tea” instead of “2.Tea”

Comment: Works on safari 13.1.1 https://i.imgur.com/J2NPNlh.png , any more details?

Comment: Not working with iPhone iOS 14.3